# Yocto INSANE_SKIP ignored

Tags: yocto

I've created an npm package recipe for node-red-node-serialport using

```
devtool add "npm://registry.npmjs.org;package=node-red-node-serialport;version=1.0.1"
```

The problem is when building I get:

```
WARNING: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_compile: Use of configs argument of NpmEnvironment.run() function is deprecated. Please use args argument instead.
WARNING: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_compile: Use of configs argument of NpmEnvironment.run() function is deprecated. Please use args argument instead.
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/prebuilds/android-arm/node.napi.armv7.node' from node-red-node-serialport was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/prebuilds/android-arm64/node.napi.armv8.node' from node-red-node-serialport was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/prebuilds/linux-arm/node.napi.armv6.node' from node-red-node-serialport was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/prebuilds/linux-arm/node.napi.armv7.node' from node-red-node-serialport was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/prebuilds/linux-arm64/node.napi.armv8.node' from node-red-node-serialport was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.napi.glibc.node' from node-red-node-serialport was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red-node-serialport/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/prebuilds/linux-x64/node.napi.musl.node' from node-red-node-serialport was already stripped, this will prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
ERROR: node-red-node-serialport-1.0.1-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/alex/Projects/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/node-red-node-serialport/1.0.1-r0/temp/log.do_package.75444
ERROR: Task (/home/alex/Projects/yocto/meta-t5/recipes-devtools/node-red-node-serialport/node-red-node-serialport_1.0.1.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

So I've tried to add

```
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "already-stripped"
```

in the recipe and in a bbappend but I still get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution, since I'm using Honister the correct syntax for the ignore command is:

```
INSANE_SKIP:${PN} += "already-stripped"
```